# How to handle two data type in the same API android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have an API response. When data is purchased it gives as a JSONObject else a null string.

How do I process both the data types.
If I try to specify Any as the data type is model class, I am not able to retrieve the data in the JSONObject.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a null, you can simply check if the key exists before calling `getString`:

```
    private fun JSONObject.getStringOrNull(key: String): String? {
        return when {
            this.has(key) -> try { getString(key) } catch (e: Exception) { null }
            else -> null
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun runTest() {
        val json = """
            { "name":"Bob Ross", "email":null }
        """.trimIndent()

        val obj = JSONObject(json)
        val name = obj.getStringOrNull("name")
        val email = obj.getStringOrNull("email")

        println(name)
        println(email)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonElement to store the data in the model class.Since primitive data types also extend JsonElement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).